# How Messenger.com & Facebook.com share login / user data?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, cross-domain, messenger

I recently had a use-case of sharing login / user data between two different domains without doing SSO or extra-login-step.

I want user to login on app-a.com, when he goes to app-b.com, it will auto-login without any action or at least show him his data to login in one click.

When you are logged-in on facebook.com and go to messenger.com **for the first time**, that is actually what happens.

[image]

How do facebook.com and messenger.com share login / user data?

I first thought it was an Iframe, but there's no iframe in the page when I check with the Chrome Cosole.

I also checked the AJAX requests but nothing readable there.

How do they do this?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: never did... But my guess is maybe they use an iframe with postMessage but I can't find any iframe in the page so I don't really know what's going on.